# How many ways we can divide '$n$' distinct items into $r$ identical groups where a group must have at-least one item?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways we can divide '$n$' distinct items into $r$ identical groups where a group must have at-least one item?

I am looking for some approach for solving this problem.

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "identical"?

Comment: @Rasmus:"identical" = "indistinguishable".

Comment: So, if you say "identical group" you mean "group consisting of identical elements"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is addressed exactly via the [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). In particular, there is an explicit formula
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ r \end{matrix}\right\} = \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{j=0}^{r}(-1)^j{r \choose j} (r-j)^n.$$

Comment: But the OP wants the subsets to be identical (whatever he means by that).

Comment: I took "identical" to mean "indistinguishable" or "unlabeled".

Comment: and if the groups are also distinct then we have to just multiply this with $r!$ which is $r! \times \left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ r \end{matrix}\right\}$